# Which would be a quicker (and better) tool for querying data stored in the Parquet format - Spark SQL, Athena or ElasticSearch?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, elasticsearch, etl, amazon-athena

Am currently building an ETL pipeline, which outputs tables of data (order of ~100+ GBs) to a downstream interactive dashboard, which allows filtering the data dynamically (based on pre-defined & indexed filters).

Have zeroed in on using **PySpark / Spark for the initial ETL phase**.
Next, this processed data will be **summarised** (*simple counts, averages, etc.*) & **then visualised** in the interactive dashboard.

Towards the interactive querying part, I was wondering which tool might work best with my structured & transactional data (stored in Parquet format) -

1. Spark SQL (in memory dynamic querying)
2. AWS Athena (Serverless SQL querying, based on Presto)
3. Elastic Search (search engine)
4. Redis (Key Value DB)

Feel free to suggest alternative tools, if you know of a better option.

Comment: Seems like the sort of thing that would best be answered by trying out these tools yourself with actual sample data and queries that are representative of your actual data - rather than expecting strangers on the internet to be able to benchmark them for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the information you've provided, I am going to make several assumptions:

1. You are on AWS (hence [Elastic Search](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/) and [Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/) being options).  Therefore, I will steer you to AWS documentation.
2. As you have pre-defined and indexed filters, you have well ordered, structured data.

Going through the options listed

1. Spark SQL - If you are already considering [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) and you are already on AWS, then you can leverage AWS [Elastic Map Reduce](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/details/spark/).
2. AWS Athena (Serverless SQL querying, based on Presto) - Athena is a powerful tool.  It lets you query data stored on S3, which is quite cost effective.  However, building workflows in Athena can require a bit of work as you'll spend a lot of time managing files on S3.  Historically, Athena can only produce CSV output, so it often works best as the final stage in a Big Data Pipeline.  However, with support for [CTAS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table-as.html) statements, you can now output data in multiple formats such as Parquet with multiple compression algorithms.
3. [Elastic Search](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/) (search engine) - Is not really a query tool, so it is likely not part of the core of this pipeline.
4. Redis (Key Value DB) - Redis is an in memory key-value data store.  It is generally used to provide small bits of information to be rapidly consumed by applications in use cases such as [caching and session management](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/what-is-redis/).  Therefore, it does not seem to fit your use case.  If you want some hands on experience with Redis, I recommend [Try Redis](https://try.redis.io/).

I would also look into [Amazon Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_US&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=redshift_b&sc_content=redshift_e&sc_detail=aws%20redshift&sc_category=redshift&sc_segment=96578642442&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=US&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!96578642442!e!!g!!aws%20redshift&ef_id=V8j-3AAAAeKgd9i5:20171228141147:s).

For further reading, read [Big Data Analytics Options on AWS](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Big_Data_Analytics_Options_on_AWS.pdf).

As @Damien_The_Unbeliever recommended, there will be no substitute for your own prototyping and benchmarking.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, @Zerodf!
Yes, forgot to mention-we are using the AWS environment.
Certainly agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever that eventually, I myself need to deploy and test all options for the optimal setup.
Thanks for clarifying the parts about ES & Redis.
Based on your answer, I think Spark SQL will require the least dev effort currently. For quicker query response, can consider working with Presto / Impala in the next stage, instead of Athena.
Appreciate the help!

Comment: Just to clarify, the query response time in Athena is fine (assuming proper data partitioning).  The issue is that Athena only supports un-compressed CSV files as an output format.  Therefore, if you have a process like Query_A -> Query_B -> Query_C, you can't leverage Athena's support for compressed data, partitioning, and columnar formats for Query_B and Query_C without unloading, transforming, and reloading data into S3.

Comment: FYI...Athena has now added support for CTAS queries which offer many output options in addition to uncompressed CSV.

Answer (score 2):

Athena is not limited to .csv.  In fact using binary compressed formats like parquet are a best practice for use with Athena, because it substantially reduces query times and cost. I have used AWS firehose, lambda functions and glue crawlers for converting text data to a compressed binary format for querying via Athena.  When I have had issues with processing large data volumes, the issue was forgetting to raise the default Athena limits set for the accounts.  I have a friend who processes gigantic volumes of utility data for predictive analytics, and he did encounter scaling problems with Athena, but that was in its early days.

I also work with ElasticSearch with Kibana as a text search engine and we use the AWS Log Analytics "solution" based on ElasticSearch and Kibana.  I like both.  Athena is best for working with huge volumes of log data, because it is more economical to work with it in a compressed binary format.  A terabyte of JSON text data reduces down to approximately 30 gig or less in parquet format.  Our developers are more productive when they use ElasticSearch/Kibana to analyze problems in their log files, because ElasticSeach and Kibana are so easy to use.  The curator Lambda function that controls logging retention times and is a part of AWS Centralized logging is also very convenient.

Comment: Excellent point, Athena supports a number of serializers/deserializers.  Additionally, support for CTAS queries has been added and you can leverage those to set output type and compression.

Answer (score 0):

you can use amazon quicksight , it has spice to do the query.. and can do visualisation at the same time..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).